# Unity, Prism, FSharp

Tags: f#, prism, unity-container

I get a resolve error when I try to inject into a FSharp library but not wen I do so with a CSharp library.

I have 3 projects :

- A main application in csharp
- A CSharp project containing a class whose constructor requires a IUnityContainer that gets instantiated fine
- A FSharp project containing a class whose constructor requires a IUnityContainer that can't instantiate with error

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "ModuleDBGraphFS.ModuleEntityGraphFS", name = "(none)". Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - **The current type,
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, is an interface and cannot
>   be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?**
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving ModuleDBGraphFS.ModuleEntityGraphFS,(none)   Resolving
>   parameter "container" of constructor
>   ModuleDBGraphFS.ModuleEntityGraphFS(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer
>   container, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionManager manager)
>       Resolving Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer,(none)

Application class in the 1st project (WPF project, you add prism, remove the startupuri from app.xaml, add on the code behind for the bootstrapper )

```cs
namespace WpfApplication
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
// OK       moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleDBGraph.ModuleEntityGraph));
// KO       moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleDBGraphFS.ModuleEntityGraphFS)); 
        }
    }
}
```

In the C# project

```cs
public class ModuleEntityGraph : IModule
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _manager;

    public ModuleEntityGraph(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager manager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _manager = manager;
    }

    void IModule.Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

in the F# project

```ml
type ModuleEntityGraphFS(container:IUnityContainer, manager:IRegionManager) =
    do printfn "hi"
    interface Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModule with 
        member x.Initialize() = 
            do ()
```

Comment: Are your references the same? That error message is pointing out that you don't have an `IUnityContainer` mapping setup.

Comment: I have the same references... It is odd that the mapping would be there when calling one, and not the other. I will try on home PC..

Comment: I can't reproduce on my Mac. I must be missing something and will report what exactly later...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the **Nuget** script for prism added reference in my module project to

```
C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.Unity\1.2.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
```

While the shell project itself was referencing

```
WpfApplication3\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
```

A fresh solution that I started made me see the problem.
Hence the odd message that it could not resolve UnityContainer itself (which should be registered somewhere by Prism Unity extensions....)